# PowerShell Here-String that keeps newlines

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

The PowerShell code:

```
$string = @'
Line 1

Line 3
'@
$string
```

Outputs:

```
Line 1
Line 3
```

But I want it to output:

```
Line 1

Line 3
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It does keep the newlines in both PS3.0 and PS2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ISE works fine and in `script` works too.
I don't remember where, but I read that is a bug in the console host code and empty lines are discarded when entered interactively for here-string.
At the moment I can't test if in Powershell V.3.0 console bug is fixed.

Link to the issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/571644/a-here-string-cannot-contain-blank-line

Workaround: add a backticks `

```
$string = @"
Line 1
`
Line 3
"@
```

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm this bug still exists in the console with PS V3

Comment: Can confirm this still exists in PS V5

Comment: Still existed in PS v5.1.14409.1018 (Windows 8.1) but corrected since at least PS v5.1.18362.752 (Windows 10 1909)

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use:
`"@+[environment]::NewLine+[environment]::NewLine+@"`
which may look ugly but works as needed.
The upper example would then be:

```
$string = @"
Line 1
"@+[environment]::NewLine+[environment]::NewLine+@"
Line 3
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, especially if you don't want to alter the here-string itself. This quick solution works great for me as it reinstates the expected behaviour of New-Line character (CRLF) stored within a Here-String / Verbatim-String ***without having to alter the Here-string*** itself. What you can do is either:

```
$here_str = $here_str -split ([char]13+[char]10)
```

OR

```
$here_str = $here_str -split [Environment]::NewLine
```

To test, you can do a line-count:

```
($here_str).Count
```

**Here is your example:**

```
$string = @'
Line 1

Line 3
'@

#Line-Count *Before*:
$string.Count         #1

$string = $string -split [Environment]::NewLine

#Line-Count *After*:
$string.Count         #3

$string
```

Output:

```
Line 1

Line 3
```

HTH